# accented/non-accented characters in mySQL's varchar

Tags: mysql, internationalization, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters

Does mySQL treat accented and non-accented character as the same. For example "é" is same as "e" ?

From the following simple test it looks like it.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `ct` (`eid` varchar(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`eid`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)

mysql> insert into ct values ('décor');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into ct values ('decor');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'decor' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

For my application 'décor' and 'decor' are 2 different values. Can someone help me get around it?

Any help will be useful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the [charset and the collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset.html) you have defined for your base and your tables.